# Sometimes when I start a video in vlc player the space bar restarts the video instead of pausing/playing, how can I fix that?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, hotkeys, raspbian

As the title says, sometimes when I start a video in vlc player the space bar doesn't work as expected.
I can watch 20 minutes of a program, and when I press the space bar to pause the video it restarts it instead.
This isn't always the case, sometimes it works as expected and sometimes it doesn't, however, once it decides to restart with a press of the space bar then it doesn't work again as play/pause until I restart vlc player.
How can I fix that?
In the hotkeys section of the preferences it says that the space bar is set to play/pause.

I'm running vlc player on raspbain on a raspberry pi.